# Как передать данные в метод действия?

Tags: c#, asp.net

На странице есть

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Period, SelectListItemsSource.NalogPeriodList, new {@id = "period"})
```

По нажатию на ссылку

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Главная", "ShowInvoicesDetails", new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId = "invoices-details", HttpMethod = "GET"})
```

передается вызов на метод действия `ShowInvoicesDetails()`, как можно выбрать значение `value` выбранного поля в выпадающем списке, чтобы он попал в метод действия? без формы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно сделать через Ajax.BeginForm:

View:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ShowInvoicesDetails", "ВашКонтроллер", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "invoices-details", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Period, SelectListItemsSource.NalogPeriodList, new { @id = "period" })
    <a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit(); return false;">Главная</a>
}
```

Контроллер:

```
public ActionResult ShowInvoicesDetails(ВашТипPeriod Period)
{
   //Ваша обработка
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать JavaScript. Достаточно добавить функцию:

```
function send()
{
     var elem= document.getElementById("elementId");
     location.href = 'site.ru/invoices-details?param=' + elem.value;
}
```

И использовать ссылку вида:

```
<a href="javascript:send()">link</a>
```

Вместо `elementId` заменить на id элемента, `param` на имя параметра, `value` на требуемое свойство.

[Ветка с обсуждением проблемы](http://forum.vingrad.ru/topic-117304.html)

Comment: сделал вот так function send() {
        var elem = getElementById("period");
        location.href = "/Main/ShowInvoicesDetails?period=" + elem.value;
    }, но ссылка теперь вообще не работает

Comment: @IgorOsipov попробуйте полную ссылку указать, включая домен